# Windows Electron Application Packaged with Electron Packager not displaying properly in task bar

Tags: node.js, windows, wix, windows-installer, electron

I'm using Electron 1.4.13, and electron-packager 8.5.0. This is happening on Windows 7, 8, and 10. I am not using electron-builder because Squirrel did not meet all the requirements I needed for an installer so I am using Wix to create the Windows installer.

What is happening is that I define all of the file metadata with electron-packager, but whenever I run the application and right click the icon in the task bar, it says Electron instead of the file name. I've seen solutions that recommend creating a shortcut, but this is not an option, no shortcuts can be created from this application.

In the two images below, the first displays the executable's properties, and the second displays what is seen on the task bar. I also saw recommendations of setting the App User Model ID in the NodeJS code which I've done immediately after the app is ready:

```
app.setAppUserModelId('Company.ExampleName.Ex');
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm still experiencing this problem? Is there some other file metadata I can change to get this right?

[image: The file properties of the executable]

[image: Windows task bar on windows 7]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ProductName` property in `--version-string`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a value for the **--version-string** parameter in your call to electron-packager. This property is specific to Windows.

```
electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --version-string.FileDescription=Company.ExampleName.Ex --asar
```

Comment: I already am currently supplying a FileDescription in my call to electron-packager.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an [open issue at Electrons Github page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/caprine/issues/145), you could chime in there and try to get the attention of one of the contributors.

Comment: Looks like that issue links to another issue on the Electron Github page that's closed, even though reading some of the comments on the Electron Github issue some people are still experiencing this problem.

Comment: Yeah, you could also try to repoen the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

package.json file edit your AppName

```
"name": "Appname",
"productName": "Appname",
```

And use  ( --version-string.ProductName="AppName" ) electron-packager

```
electron-packager . AppName --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=icon/favicon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="AppName"icon
```

This feature is specific to Windows. !!!